# Flex Slider small carousel images are not clickable

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

On this page: http://groupecopley.staging.wpengine.com/properties/redefined-classic-luxury/

I have a Flex Slider right at the top.
If you click on any of the small images in the slider, they should appear in the large part of the slider. However this functionality is not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Another un-used JS script was conflicting with my slider. I removed the old script and all works well.